# Its Dangerous creating a token: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: python, flask

I have an email confirmation feature on my Flask application. For this to work, I must create a token which will go in a confirmation link. To create the token I'm using Its Dangerous like so:

```
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer
ts = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config["SECRET_KEY"])
token = ts.dumps(email, salt='email-confirm-key')
confirm = url_for('confirm', token=token, _external=True)
```

After running this, I receive an error stating `cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects` from the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/myapp/myapp/views/confirmation.py", line 62, in resend
    activateEmail(email)
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/myapp/myapp/views/functions.py", line 34, in activateEmail
    token = ts.dumps(email, salt='email-confirm-key')
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 566, in dumps
    rv = self.make_signer(salt).sign(payload)
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 412, in sign
    return value + sep + self.get_signature(value)
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 347, in get_signature
    key = self.derive_key()
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Documents/Web-Development/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 334, in derive_key
    self.secret_key).digest()
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

I'm unsure what the issue is, as `email` is a string and the salt is one too. What could be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
ts = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config["SECRET_KEY"])
```

It looks like your `app.config["SECRET_KEY"]` is not being set correctly. If you replace that line with this

```
ts = URLSafeTimedSerializer('test')
```

You should find that it works. So you need to find out why `app.config["SECRET_KEY"]` is not being set correctly.